# Underfined constant name assumed 'name'

Tags: php, arrays

I keep getting this error. Can someone please elaborate on what the solution might be?

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'

```
<?php foreach ($replacement_array as &$replacement_array) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $replacement_array[number]?>">
    <?php echo $replacement_array[name]?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Original array code:

```
$replacement_array[] = array('name'=>'1) 200W High Bay (400W Subst.)', 'name_2'=>'200W High Bay', 'name_3'=>'High Bay', 'number'=>'1', 'replacement_cal'=>'200', 'life'=>'100000');
$replacement_array[] = array('name'=>'2) 80W High Bay (150W Subst.)', 'name_2'=>'80W High Bay', 'number'=>'2', 'name_3'=>'High Bay', 'replacement_cal'=>'80', 'life'=>'50000');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make those array keys into strings. Like this:

```
<?php foreach ($replacement_array as &$replacement_array) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $replacement_array['number']?>">
    <?php echo $replacement_array['name']?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Otherwise they are parsed as if they are code or global functions etc, but obviously there aren't any.

Comment: Thankyou - this has been helpful. Now I feel stupid as I did the single quotes with another part of the code... which fixed. I missed this one though.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi there,

Sorry for bumping up an old thread, but the comments here suggest single quotes, which doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is the code:
     $replacement_array[] = array('name'=>'1) 200W High Bay (400W Subst.)', 'name_2'=>'200W High Bay', 'name_3'=>'High Bay', 'number'=>'1', 'replacement_cal'=>'200', 'life'=>'100000');

Here is the error:
Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'